.OnKeyPress doesn't work on TextField ForEach Array
I have 6 different textFields set up by a ForEach like so:
ForEach(0..<6) { index in
    TextField("", text: $OTPStringArray[index])
        .frame(width: 45, height: 48)
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .focused($OTPFocused, equals: index)
        .tag(index)
        .keyboardType(.default)
        .onKeyPress(.delete, action: {
            print("DELETED")
            return .handled
        })
        .onChange(of: OTPStringArray[index]) { oldValue, newValue in
            print("VALUES")
            print(oldValue)
            print(newValue)
            if OTPStringArray[index].count > 1 {
                OTPStringArray[index] = String(OTPStringArray[index].suffix(1))
            }
            
            if !newValue.isEmpty {
                if OTPFocused != 5 {
                    OTPFocused = (OTPFocused ?? 0) + 1
                } else {
                    pagingIndex = 7
                }
            } else {
                OTPFocused = (OTPFocused ?? 0) - 1
            }

            
        }
}

I need to go back to the previous textfield when the delete key is pressed. But because the TextField at index cannot be specified, .OnKeyPress doesn't work. .onChange works because it can be specified which index in the (of: ...) modifier. How can I detect when the delete key is pressed in any one of these text fields?

try moving the .onKeyPress() outside the ForEach.
Add some logic in it to deal with the OTPFocused index.

@workingdogsupportUkraine What would the logic look like to deal with the OTPFocused?

@workingdog did you ever find a solution?

is this for a macOS App, or a iPad App with a hardware keyboard? AFAIK, .onKeyPress only works with hardware keyboard.

@Mr.Man I posted an answer a couple of days ago. Would be nice to know whether it works for you or not. If it does, please mark it as a solution.

@workingdogsupportUkraine even with hardware keyboard, .onKeyPress doesn't do anything for some reason

@workingdogsupport I notice how with the .onChange function you can specify which string is being changed (ex. .onChange(of: OTPStringArray[index])), but with .onKeyPress there is no of: input

The delete key action is part of the TextField interaction when in focus,
and so does not trigger a onKeyPress. You could consider using
the more user intuitive way of switching focus using the up and down arrow.
This is easy to setup and works well in my tests.
Note, .onKeyPress works only with a hardware keyboard, not the keyboard on a iPhone.

Although your code is incomplete and not testable, it should work when using a hardware keyboard, but not when typing on virtual/screen keyboard, since .onKeyPress only detects key presses on a hardware keyboard.
Logically, a backspace keypress is simply removing the last character from a given string, meaning:

Upon the backspace keypress, the length of the new textfield string will be one character less than before pressing.
The remaining characters are a subset of the string before the keypress.

To detect changes in a textfield without displaying it directly, meaning you shouldn't be able to see the character being deleted and possibly reverted to its full version, you need a way to conditionally set the state the textfield is bound to.
To do so, you could use an intermediate state to bind the textfield to and then based on changes to that state, you would update the respective item in the array, but an easier way is to use a custom binding.
With a custom binding, you can read from one place and then conditionally set the new value as needed.
Here's the working code:
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldOnKeyPress: View {
    
    //State values
    @State private var stringArray = ["string1", "", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6"]
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Int?
    
    //Body
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<6) {index in
                TextField("", text: Binding( // <- use a custom binding
                    
                    // Read from `stringArray`
                    get: { stringArray[index] },
                    
                    //Write to 'stringArray conditionally
                    set: { newValue in
                        
                        let oldValue = stringArray[index]
                        
                        //Determine the index of the previous field
                        let previousField = index < 1 ? nil : index - 1
                        
                        //If the new value is a subset of the old value
                        if oldValue.hasPrefix(newValue),
                           newValue.count < oldValue.count  { // and the new value has fewer characters than the old value
                            
                            //Change focus to the previous field
                            focusedField = previousField
                        }
                        //if field is empty
                        else if oldValue == "" {
                            stringArray[index] = " " //add a space in order to be able to detect changes
                        }
                        //if a character was typed after the space character
                        else if stringArray[index]  == " ", newValue.count > oldValue.count {
                            //Drop the empty space since no longer needed and it shouldn't be part of the field string
                            stringArray[index] = String(newValue.dropFirst())
                        }
                        else {
                            stringArray[index] = newValue
                        }
                    }
                ))
                .id(index)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: index)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    TextFieldOnKeyPress()
}

UPDATE:
Updated code logic to account for the requirement when field is empty, that I initially missed.
Since there isn't really a way to detect a delete in an empty string without a hardware keyboard, I used a workaround where a space character is added if the field is empty.
To compensate, if a field has a space as first character and other characters are typed after, the space at the beginning will be removed.

even with the hardware keyboard, .delete is still not detected

Also, the setter isn't called if there's no change. So if the String starts out as "", and you press delete, the String is still "", so the setter isn't called.

@Mr.Man Just to be clear, are you talking about deleting backwards (aka Backspace) or deleting forwards (like a hardware keyboard Delete key)? Also, is there an assumption that a hardware keyboard will be used or an on-screen keyboard?

backspace. The only delete key on the iOS keyboard. The only keyboard that will be used is the keyboard on the iPhone itself
